# Vue.js v-if not reacting to variable change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm playing around with vue.js and have some struggle in using v-if correctly.

i'm trying to have a conditional template rendering inside a template. in the created method, the variable `isloaded` is set to true, which should lead the template to be rerendered and let the "Loading Data" message disappear.

However, the log indicated, the delay of 2s works, so the callback is reached, but it looks like i'm not updating the data variables correctly.

I tried already several things and now i changed "true/false" to be strings in order to be closer to the exampled given on the official homepage, but still no success. i hope you can help me and therefor thanks a lot in advance.

please find below the interesting codesnippets:

```js
var step1 = Vue.component('step1', {
  template: '#step1',
  data: function() {
    return {
      accounts: [],
      isloaded: 'false'
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log("created");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("times over");
      this.isloaded = 'true';
      this.accounts = [{
        id: 1234,
        name: "germany"
      }];
    }, 2000);
  },
  methods: {
    loaded: function() {
      console.log(this.isloaded === 'true');
      return this.isloaded === 'true';
    }
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#main'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<template id="step1">
  <div class="step1">
    <h1>Welcome please choose your account:</h1>
    <template v-if="isloaded === 'false'">
      <p>Loading Data</p>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <select>
        <template v-for="account in accounts">
          <option :value="account.id">{{ account.name }}</option>
        </template>
      </select>
    </template>

  </div>
</template>

<div id="main">
  <step1></step1>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't fix your issue but may prevent further issues down the line. Since `isLoaded` is a boolean, you should treat it as such. 'true' and 'false' should just be `true` and `false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Vue.js - Reactivity in Depth docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue):

> For example, when you set vm.someData = 'new value', the component
> will not re-render immediately. It will update in the next “tick”,
> when the queue is flushed.

With the data being mutated in the created lifecycle hook, we need to use `$nextTick` More info on that can be found in the above page.

```js
var step1 = Vue.component('step1', {
  template: '#step1',
  data: function() {
    return {
      accounts: [],
      isloaded: false
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log("created");
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("times over");
      self.$nextTick(function() {
        self.isloaded = true;
        self.accounts = [{
          id: 1234,
          name: "germany"
        }];
      })

    }, 2000);
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#main'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<template id="step1">
  <div class="step1">
    <h1>Welcome please choose your account:</h1>
    <template v-if="isloaded===false">
      <p>Loading Data</p>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <select>
        <template v-for="account in accounts">
          <option :value="account.id">{{ account.name }}</option>
        </template>
      </select>
    </template>

  </div>
</template>

<div id="main">
  <step1></step1>
</div>
```

However, if you place the code that is loading the data inside a method, and call that method from the `created` hook. It works without `$nextTick`.

```
methods: {
    loadData: function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("times over");
            self.isloaded = true;
            self.accounts = [{
                id: 1234,
                name: "germany"
            }];
        }, 2000);
    }
},
created: function() {
    console.log("created");
    this.loadData();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The scope of `this` is incorrect. The `function ()` syntax creates its own scope. You can save the correct scope in one var and use that, like following:

```
created: function() {
  var that = this
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("times over");
    that.isloaded = 'true';
    that.accounts = [{
      id: 1234,
      name: "germany"
    }];
  }, 2000);
},
```

Alternatively, you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which does not bind it's own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target).

```
created: function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("times over");
    this.isloaded = 'true';
    this.accounts = [{
      id: 1234,
      name: "germany"
    }];
  }, 2000);
},
```

Comment: Hah, seems I over-thought my answer. Good job! Edit: It's worth noting that there is no support for IE11 with arrow functions, natively: http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this can be caused by an error in the template. For example, I used an undefined method in the `v-else` case, and that's why looks like `v-if` is not reactive. The problem will be solved if you remove the undefined method in `v-else` or define that method.

**Note**: Even if the method is defined on the instance, be sure to check that you are sending a valid value as parameter.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      isLoading: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoading = false
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-if="isLoading">
    Loading...
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    loading finished
    
    {{ an_undefined_method() }}
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting an idea! I use a *defined* method but there was no some field in an object what was checking in the method.

Answer (score -2):

Update your method to have just one =, and remove the return.

```
methods: {
  loaded: function() {
    console.log(this.isloaded === 'true');
    this.isloaded = 'true';
  }
}
```