# Axios and VueJS, function(response) is not setting a list

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I have an request to get some data and add it to a variable,

When I use:

```
.then(function(response) {
    this.persons = response.data;
});
```

It does not assign `response.data` to `this.persons` but when I do the following:

```
.then(response => this.persons = response.data);
```

It assigns it fine to use. Please see the js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/trhhtyxr/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41960694/1610034), [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not bind it's own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target). Arrow functions are always [anonymous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions.

Scope of `this` changes inside a [function()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) block and it [does not refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) to the currently executing function, while with arrow function, `this` refers to the currently executing function only.