# this.$http.get is not working inside methods vue js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-spark

I am working with Laravel + spark + vue js.

Blade file

```
<draggable class="col-md-12" :list="emergencies" :element="draggableOuterContainer" @end="onEnd">
```

Js file

```
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
module.exports = {
data() {        
    return {
        emergencies:[]
    };
},
components: {
    draggable,
},
created() {
    this.getEmergencies();
},
methods: {
    getEmergencies() {
        this.$http.get('/ajax-call-url')
            .then(response => {
                this.emergencies = response.data;
            });
    },        
    onEnd: function(evt){
        var counter = 1;
        this.emergencies.forEach(function(user, index) {
            this.$http.get('/ajax-call-url/')
            .then(response => {   
            });    
            counter++;  
        });
    }
}
};
```

Here I have drag and Drop, On Drop, I call "onEnd" function and getting following error.

> TypeError: this is undefined

Here this.emergencies.forEach is working but it is giving error on this.$http.get

Any suggestions, what can be the solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using function syntax, use arrow functions, as scope of this changes inside function:

```
onEnd: function(evt){
    var counter = 1;
    this.emergencies.forEach((user, index) => {
        this.$http.get('/ajax-call-url/')
        .then(response => {   
        });    
        counter++;  
    });
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039797/1610034) for explanation.