# undefined property in vue 2 basic test

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi i am trying to use Vue in a laravel app but i have some issues. 
Basically i need to retrieve data from a get request and build some results based on it. 
The problem is that i don't even get to correctly retrieve the data inside my array variable. I better explain

in my app.js i load my vue instance

```
Vue.component('search', require('./components/search.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
});
```

in my main.blade.php i insert my vue component

```
<search class="row expanded container"></search>
```

this is my vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Conhenhmponent</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!

                        {{test}}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data () {
        return {
            test:"this is my sample",
            results: []
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        console.log(this); // here my obj exists  
        console.log('Component mounted.') // it works
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/search?q=qwfqw")
        .then(function(resp){
            if(typeof resp.data == 'string') {
                resp.data = JSON.parse(resp.data);
            }
            console.log(resp.data); // here the object exists
            this.results = resp.data;
        });
    }
}


</script>
```

The page loads but i get an error that says the results var is undefined.
How can i fill my result var with the get data? what's the right way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios and VueJS, function(response) is not setting a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039714/axios-and-vuejs-functionresponse-is-not-setting-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

It's a scoping issue. In your code the `this` inside the callback refers to the function itself, not the vue instance, so it's `undefined`. To resolve this you should use an arrow function (Laravel will already have ES6 correctly configured) which will ensure `this` refers to the vue instance:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/search?q=qwfqw")
 .then(resp => {
     if(typeof resp.data == 'string') {
         resp.data = JSON.parse(resp.data);
     }
     console.log(resp.data); // here the object exists
     this.results = resp.data;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript is determined by what called the function and not where it is defined. One way to resolve your problem is to store a reference to `this` in another variable using `var self = this;` and then reference the results like  `self.results = resp.data;`

Another way to use the `bind` function, Arrow functions. With arrow functions the scope of this changes to where it defined lexically.

```
mounted () {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this); // here my obj exists  
        console.log('Component mounted.') // it works
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/search?q=qwfqw")
        .then(function(resp){
            if(typeof resp.data == 'string') {
                resp.data = JSON.parse(resp.data);
            }
            console.log(resp.data); // here the object exists
            self.results = resp.data;
        });
    }
```