# How to render data with AJAX in Vuejs 2?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

I have problems while trying to set **data** in a Vue instance
 (example in: https://jsfiddle.net/a5naw6f8/4/ )

I assign the values to **data** property by AJAX. I can render **exam** object but when I want to access to an inner array **exam.questions.length** I get an error:

> "TypeError: exam.questions is undefined"

This is my code :

```
// .js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        id: "1",
        exam: {}
    },
    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            $.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/15lkz66wy3fut03/data.json", 
                (data) => {
                    this.exam = data;
                }
            );
        }
    }
});

<!-- .html -->
<div id="app">
    <h1>ID: {{ id }}</h1>
    <h1>Exam: {{ exam }}</h1>

    <!--  exam.questions array is undefined -->
    <!-- <h1>Questions length: {{ exam.questions.length }}</h1> -->
</div>
```

I found a similar problem but it was relative to this reserved word scope:
[Vuejs does not render data from ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826612/vuejs-does-not-render-data-from-ajax)

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems:

- Your JSON file isn't valid. The trailing commas after the the `false` cause the parser to choke.
- You aren't parsing your JSON (which is why you probably didn't see the JSON error). Once you fix the JSON file, you need to parse it with something like `this.exam = JSON.parse(data)`  rather than assigning the string to `this.exam`
- Once you do that, you can test for the object in the template with `v-if` before trying to access its properties:
  `<h1 v-if="exam.questions">Questions length: {{ exam.questions.length }}</h1>`

`v-if` will prevent the attempt to access `exam.questions.length` until the ajax request has returned data

Comment: Many thanks for the reply **Mark_M**. The subject is that if I want to enter a new condition using a computed property the same error reappears:
"TypeError: this.exam.questions is undefined": 

[Modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/9gw2Luax/29/](https://jsfiddle.net/9gw2Luax/29/)

Comment: I found a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9gw2Luax/30/  I think the problem was at the point of the first render template **exam.questions** property does not exist yet (because asynchrony of setting data).
But when if I defined the structure of data with no assigment then properties exists and there were no errors.