# Vue.js 2: Get data from AJAX method

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue, and I'm attempting to grab the data via AJAX in a method.

I know the method is working.

Here's the Vue code:

```
Vue.component('sub-folder', {
    props: ['folder'],
    template: '<a href="#">{{folder.title}}</a>'
});

var buildFoldersList = new Vue({
    el: '#sub-folders',
    data: {
        foldersList: this.foldersList
    },
    methods: {
        buildFolders: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'api/folder/get_subfolders/' + browser_folder_id,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "folder_id": browser_folder_id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Data");
                    console.log(data);
                    this.foldersList = data;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="list-group" id="sub-folders">
    <sub-folder v-for="folder in foldersList" :key="folder.folder_id" v-bind:folder="folder"></sub-folder>
</div>
```

At the moment, the containing template is running, but since the method isn't getting executed, there's no data.

I've tried everything I know to trigger the method, but I've run out of ideas.

Comment: From where are you calling `buildFolders ` method?

Comment: U dont call method buildFolders. Use one of [hooks](https://vuejs-tips.github.io/cheatsheet/) to make request 
And it is recommended to use [axios for ajax](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not calling the `buildFolders` method at all, you can call it from the [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) hook of vue.js like following:

```
var buildFoldersList = new Vue({
    el: '#sub-folders',
    data: {
        foldersList: []
    },
    created () {
       this.buildFolders()
    },
    methods: {
        buildFolders: function () {   
            var self = this 
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'api/folder/get_subfolders/' + browser_folder_id,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "folder_id": browser_folder_id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Data");
                    console.log(data);
                    self.foldersList = data;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also you can relook at how you are using this, as scope of `this` will change in `$.ajax` method as happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882183/1610034), see the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039797/1610034).

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, as I said, tried everything I know to trigger the method, but I've run out of ideas. What you're seeing is that last iteration.

Comment: I see that it's returning an object, but I don't understand how to access it — I'm unable to find data in it.

Comment: @WayneSmallman You dont need to depend on the value returned in the method, You have to just get the method executed and assign the vue instance variable in the method.

Comment: Without the data, it doesn't work. I changed the code to: `self.foldersList = data.result;` which now works.